# Populate treeview with recordset

Tags: c++, winapi, ado

I have a dialog box that behaves as a child of the main window. Dialog box has treeview control. They are created using resource editor and WinAPI.

I am using ADO and C++ to populate treeview with some data from database. Unfortunately, I do not get the expected result.

To understand my problem, I will provide the description of the columns in the database table I get data from:

- ID -> autonumber
- BrojUgovora -> string  // ContractNumber
- many other fields...

Here are the relevant values for the above table:

```
ID | BrojUgovora
-----------------
 1 | qwert
 2 | prvi ugovor
 3 | drugi ugovor
```

---

After I run my code, I expect to get following result:
    drugi ugovor
    prvi ugovor
    qwert

but I get this:

```
drugi ugovor
prvi ugovor
ID           -------> why column name instead of column value???
```

When I comment out the part where I store ID into treeview node via lParam, I get proper result.

I need to store the ID into lParam, so deleting that part of my code is not an option.

---

Here is the function I call in `WM_INITDIALOG`:

```
/*********** REMARKS ***************
/**** Fills treeview control with the contract number 
/**** In treeview node's LPARAM is stored the value of the primary key
/**** Returns the number of failed attempts to load string/autonumber field
/***********************************/

int InitTreeView(HWND hDlg)
{
    // error result
    int iNumberOfFailedLoads = 0;

    //connect to database 
    ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");
    try
    {
        HRESULT hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, username, password, 
            ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        ADODB::_CommandPtr pCmd("ADODB.Command");

        pCmd->ActiveConnection = pConn;
        pCmd->CommandType = ADODB::adCmdText;
        pCmd->CommandText = L" select ID, BrojUgovora from UGOVORI;";

        ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS = pCmd->Execute(NULL, NULL, ADODB::adCmdText);

        ADODB::Fields* pFields = NULL;

        hr = pRS->get_Fields(&pFields);

        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        if (pFields && pFields->GetCount() > 0)
        {
            while (!pRS->AdoNSEOF)
            {
                // load contract values into treeview
                TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis = { 0 };
                tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
                tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_FIRST;
                tvis.item.pszText = // this is string field
                    pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"BrojUgovora")->Value.bstrVal;
                tvis.item.lParam =  // this is autonumber field
                    (LPARAM)(pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"ID")->Value.lVal);

                HTREEITEM hti = TreeView_InsertItem(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_TREE1), 
                    &tvis);

                if (NULL == hti)
                    iNumberOfFailedLoads++;

                pRS->MoveNext();
            }
            pRS->Close();
        }

        pConn->Close();
    }
    catch (_com_error &e)
    {
        if (pConn->State == ADODB::adStateOpen)
            pConn->Close();

        iNumberOfFailedLoads = -1;
    }

    return iNumberOfFailedLoads;
}
```

Here is `WM_INITDIALOG` handler:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    // needed for visual styles, long story
    EnableThemeDialogTexture(hDlg, ETDT_ENABLETAB);
    InitTreeView(hDlg);
}
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
```

### DEBUGGING RESULTS:

Here is what I get from the debugger:

```
/*********** REMARKS ***************
/**** Fills treeview control with the contract number 
/**** In treeview node's LPARAM is stored the value of the primary key
/**** Returns the number of failed attempts to load string/autonumber field
/***********************************/

int InitTreeView(HWND hDlg)
{
    // error result
    int iNumberOfFailedLoads = 0;

    //connect to database 
    ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");
    try
    {
        HRESULT hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, username, password, 
            ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        ADODB::_CommandPtr pCmd("ADODB.Command");

        pCmd->ActiveConnection = pConn;
        pCmd->CommandType = ADODB::adCmdText;
        pCmd->CommandText = L" select ID, BrojUgovora from UGOVORI;";

        ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS = pCmd->Execute(NULL, NULL, ADODB::adCmdText);

        ADODB::Fields* pFields = NULL;

        hr = pRS->get_Fields(&pFields);

        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        if (pFields && pFields->GetCount() > 0)
        {
            while (!pRS->AdoNSEOF)
            {
                // load contract values into treeview
                TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis = { 0 };
                tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
                tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_FIRST;
                tvis.item.pszText = 
                    pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"BrojUgovora")->Value.bstrVal;
                tvis.item.lParam =  // here is first breakpoint
                    (LPARAM)(pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"ID")->Value.lVal);

                // MessageBeep(0) added just so I can put breakpoint there
                MessageBeep(0);  // here is second breakpoint

                HTREEITEM hti = TreeView_InsertItem(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_TREE1), 
                    &tvis);

                if (NULL == hti)
                    iNumberOfFailedLoads++;

                pRS->MoveNext();
            }
            pRS->Close();
        }

        pConn->Close();
    }
    catch (_com_error &e)
    {
        if (pConn->State == ADODB::adStateOpen)
            pConn->Close();

        iNumberOfFailedLoads = -1;
    }

    return iNumberOfFailedLoads;
}
```

When I reach first breakpoint, string is correctly read from the database.

On second breakpoint, it "magically" changes to `ID`.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

After changing the code in the `while` loop like below, everything works:

```
while (!pRS->AdoNSEOF)
{
    wchar_t txt[50];
    memset(txt, L'\0', sizeof(txt));
    swprintf_s(txt, 50, L"%s",
        pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"BrojUgovora")->Value.bstrVal);

    //...
    tvis.item.pszText = txt;
    // the rest of the code is the same
```

*I have tried to use dynamic string to store the string from database, but have failed. I get debug assertion error. The same happens when I try to use `wstring`.*

### QUESTION:

How should I rewrite my `InitTreeView` function to avoid bug I described above?

Comment: It seems you are missing a [MoveFirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677527.aspx) call on the recordset prior to iterating over the entries.

Comment: I'm confused, is this an ADO question or a tree control question?

Comment: @Jonathan: Since the OP doesn't know whether the error is in adding treeview items or querying DB entries it contains both tags. Once the question is answered, the tags/topic can be updated appropriately.

Comment: @IInspectable Judicious use of a debugger should enable the OP to work that out for himself, and then narrow the question focus as needed.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have tried using debugger, but couldn't find where the problem lies. I apologize for the confusion I made with tags. I am working on narrowing down the problem.

Comment: @IInspectable: I have tried adding `pRS->MoveFirst` just above the `while` loop, but the problem persists. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is, which is why I made my initial comment. Are you saying you get the wrong strings from the database? Or that the wrong strings appear in the tree? Set a breakpoint after you query the database and see if the strings are right or not.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have edited my post with debugging results. I have managed to find a workaround for the problem, but not a proper solution. Looking forward to hear your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the `GetItem` method is returning a temporary value which is being lost once the function returns; so the string that `pszText` ends up pointing to has been freed/overwritten.

Try the following and see if it makes a difference:

```
            // load contract values into treeview
            _variant_t varText = pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"BrojUgovora")->Value;
            _variant_t varID = pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"ID")->Value;

            TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis = { 0 };
            tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
            tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_FIRST;
            tvis.item.pszText = varText.bstrVal;
            tvis.item.lParam =  varID.lVal;
```

Comment: Works. I suspected the same, but couldn't "pinpoint" the "culprit". It seems that you are right -> `GetItem` seems to return a temporary value that is being lost after function returns. Thank you for your help -> upvoted and officially accepted. *I guess ADO tag is not necessary here, based on your earlier comment. Should I delete or leave it?**

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Glad it works. I would get rid of the `treeview` tag since it really had nothing to do with the tree control at all.

Comment: *I would get rid of the `treeview` tag since it really had nothing to do with the tree control at all.* Done. I still do not get why everything worked fine if I ommited the part where I store `ID` into `TVINSERTSTRUCT` `lParam` member. I wish if I could get the answer to this one...

Comment: The second call to `GetItem` overwrote the memory returned by the first call. Even though the memory was no longer owned its contents  hadn't been changed and so it appeared to work.